# How to import `xlsx` in a node.js EcmaScript module wrote in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

Using Node.js v18.12.1, I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx in a node.js EcmaScript module wrote in typescript.

However, when I follow the instructions for Node.js (https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/nodejs#esm-import) like this :

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
XLSX.set_fs(fs);
```

I get the following runtime (not compile time) error:
`TypeError: XLSX.set_fs is not a function`

What is wrong with this import ?

*tsconfig.json*:

```
...
   "target": "ESNext", 
   "module": "ESNext",
...
```

*package.json*:

```
...
"type": "module"
...
```

Comment: The documentation on NPM shows `import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx.mjs';` for Node.js.

Comment: @VLAZ please provide the link, I can't find it

Comment: It's the first link you shared: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx Scroll to the "NodeJS" heading. Or jump there by searching in the page for "npm install xlsx" (its immediately after the heading). The code block is almost the same as the SheetJS Getting Started link except the import is different.

Comment: this time I get `Could not find a declaration file for module 'xlsx/xlsx.mjs'. 'c:/GitHub/sapen-db/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.` at compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older releases are technically available on the public npm registry as xlsx, but the registry is out of date. The latest version on that registry is 0.18.5

Following these steps solves the problem :
https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/nodejs#installation